# Logstash grok filter, debugger OK but failure in logstash parsing

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, logstash, logstash-grok

my grok filter is ok in grok Debugger but not work when i start logstash.

my line log

```
[Mon Aug 28 09:16:16.028821 2017] [php7:notice] [pid 11111] [client 22.22.66.66:66666] message d'erreur
```

my .conf

```
filter { 
   grok { 
      match => { "message" => "\[%{DAY:day} %{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY:monthday} %{TIME:time} %{YEAR:year}\] \[%{WORD:php}:%{WORD:logelvel}\] \[%{WORD} %{WORD:processus}\] \[%{WORD} %{IP}:%{POSINT:port}\] %{GREEDYDATA: message}" }
   } 
}
```

Result :

```
@timestamp:August 28th 2017, 10:40:22.380 offset:5,269 @version:1 input_type:log beat.hostname:ip-166-55-55-55 beat.name:ip-166-55-55-55 beat.version:5.5.1 host:ip-175-61-66-66 source:/var/log/apache2/filelog.log 
message:[Mon Aug 28 09:10:59.023093 2017] [php7:notice] [pid 11111] [client 22.22.66.66:66666] 
message d'erreur type:log tags:beats_input_codec_plain_applied, _grokparsefailure _id:AV4n_8akHhd-RttynnUH _type:log _index:index-2017.08.28 _score: -
```

Thank your very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your square parenthesis like this:

```
\[%{DAY:day} %{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY:monthday} %{TIME:time} %{YEAR:year}\] \[%{WORD:php}:%{WORD:logelvel}\] \[%{WORD} %{WORD:processus}\] \[%{WORD} %{IP}:%{POSINT:port}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

Comment: The space in `%{GREEDYDATA: message}` has to be removed or it won't work (at least in grok debugger).

Comment: Sorry, i dont see difference between both. Ok for the space

Comment: Before baudsp edits, your grok pattern missed the "\" before the square parenthesis, I suggested to add them

Comment: Thanks you for your answer but see my version, i have \ all [ . I changed space but same problem.

Comment: Try removing chunks of the from pattern from the end gradually until the parser doesn't fail anymore. This way you should understand which token is failing

Comment: @Cleoh In your question, there is still a space in `%{GREEDYDATA: message}` which has to be removed